# Expected value and variance of step of random walk with barriers

Tags: probability, random-walk, means

I have to simulate the following game

> Suppose that two players A and B each start with a stake of \$5, and bet \$0.5 on consecutive coin ﬂips. The game ends when either one of the players has won all the money, that amounts to \$10. Let $S_n$ be the fortune of player A at time n. Then $\{S_n, n \gt 0 \}$ is a symmetric random walk with absorbing barriers at 0 and 10. Estimate $E[S_n]$ and $V[S_n]$ for $n = 50$.

I made a program and that's ok. Now I would to compare my results with the theoretical values. I don't know *almost anything* in probability, so that's just a curiosity. My question is

> Which are the values of $E[S_n]$ and $V[S_n]$ in general? And for $n = 50$?

If there's no closed form, I will appreciate also an approximation (I got $E[S_n] \approx 5$ and $V[S_{50}] \approx 4.8$)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you have simulated, I'm sure you can guess the (very simple) value of  $E[S_n]$.  The proper way to simulate that is to run multiple (say, 10000 or more) experiments, get a time series for each experiment $i$ to obtain the vector   $(S_0^{(i)}, S_1^{(i)}, S_2^{(i)}, ..., S_{100}^{(i)})$,  average those values and plot the averaged values $\frac{1}{10000}\sum_{i=1}^{10000}S_n^{(i)}$ versus $n \in \{0, 1, 2, ..., 100\}$.

Comment: Yes I did, but now I want to know the theoretical results

Comment: So from those experiments you should be able to guess the value of $E[S_n]$ for each $n$ and your guess is...

Comment: My guess is 5 but I want to know if it agrees with the theory

Comment: Yes $E[S_n]=5$ for all $n$ since this is a martingale, $S_{n+1} = S_n + A_n$ where $A_n=0$ if $S_n \in \{0, 10\}$ and $E[A_n|S_n]=0$ regardless the value of $S_n$.  You might want to provide your simulated guesses for $E[S_{50}]$ and $Var(S_{50})$  in the question itself.  Here I assume coin flips are independent and equally likely to be heads or tails.

Comment: For variance I don't know because I get about 4.8, but maybe it's still 5. Thanks for your help!

Comment: For each $n$ we have $Var(S_n) = E[(S_n-E[S_n])^2] = E[(S_n-5)^2]$. Since $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}P[S_n=0]=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} P[S_n=10]=1/2$ we get $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} Var(S_n) = (0-5)^2(1/2)+(10-5)^2(1/2) = 25$. The exact value of $Var(S_n)$ can also be calculated for each $n$ but it seems to require $P[S_n \notin \{0, 10\}]$ and is a bit more involved.  I wonder if your simulated value is computing the standard deviation $\sqrt{Var(S_n)}$,  rather than the variance.

Comment: I don't know how to simulate this because for $n \to \infty$ many of the games will be over. In the simulation this means many NA and so not many values to get a correct statistic. Thanks again for the help!

Comment: There are no “not applicable” results. Make all your simulations, say, 100 steps.  It is not possible for the simulation to be “over” before time 100. If the process reaches state 10 at time 76, then it will also be 10 at time 77,78,…,100. This must be part of your data. Note that $S_{100}$ takes values in the set $\{0, 0.5, 1, 1.5, …, 10\}$.  It is not allowed to take a value “NA.”  If you are throwing away all simulations for which we hit either $0$ or $10$ before time 100, you are throwing away most of the important data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Modeling the process

Define $\mathcal{S}$ as the set of possible values for the Markov chain: 
$$\mathcal{S} = \{0, 0.5, 1, 1.5, …, 9.5, 10\}$$
Note that $S_0=5$ and $S_n \in \mathcal{S}$ for all $n \in \{0, 1, 2, …\}$.
We have 
$$S_{n+1} = S_n + A_n \quad \forall n \in \{0, 1, 2, ...\} $$
where 
$$ A_n =  \left\{ \begin{array}{ll}
(1/2)B_n &\mbox{ if $S_n \notin \{0, 10\}$} \\
0  & \mbox{ otherwise} 
\end{array}
\right.$$
where $\{B_n\}_{n=0}^{\infty}$ is an i.i.d. sequence with $P[B_n=1]=P[B_n=-1]=1/2$. 
Then 
$$\boxed{E[A_n|S_n=s] = 0 \quad, \forall s \in \mathcal{S}} \quad (Eq. 1) $$

---

#### Mean

So for each $n \in \{0, 1, 2, ...\}$ we have 
\begin{align}
E[S_{n+1}] &\overset{(a)}{=} \sum_{s \in \mathcal{S}}E[S_{n+1}|S_n=s]P[S_n=s] \\
&\overset{(b)}{=} \sum_{s \in \mathcal{S}}E[S_n + A_n|S_n=s]P[S_n=s] \\
&= \sum_{s \in \mathcal{S}}E[s + A_n|S_n=s]P[S_n=s] \\
&= \sum_{s \in \mathcal{S}}(s + E[A_n|S_n=s])P[S_n=s] \\
&\overset{(c)}{=} \sum_{s \in \mathcal{S}}sP[S_n=s] \\
&\overset{(d)}{=} E[S_n] 
\end{align}
where (a) holds by the law of total expectation; (b) holds by the fact $S_{n+1}=S_n+A_n$; (c) holds by Eq. (1); (d) holds by definition of expectation. 
Since $E[S_0]=5$ we conclude: 
$$\boxed{E[S_n]=5 \quad \forall n \in \{0, 1, 2, … \}}$$

---

#### Limiting variance

We know $E[S_n]=5$ for all $n$ and so 
$$Var(S_n) = E[(S_n-5)^2] = \sum_{s \in \mathcal{S}}(s-5)^2P[S_n=s] $$
Since the process is equally likely to end up at state $0$ or $10$ we have
\begin{align}
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} P[S_n=0] &= 1/2\\
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} P[S_n=10] &= 1/2\\
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} P[S_n=s] &= 0 \quad \forall s \notin \{0, 10\}
\end{align}
so 
$$ \boxed{\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} Var(S_n) = (0-5)^2(1/2) + (10-5)^2(1/2) = 25} $$

---

#### Details on variance

Squaring the equation $S_{n+1} = S_n + A_n$ gives 
$$S_{n+1}^2 = (S_n+A_n)^2 = S_n^2 + 2S_nA_n + A_n^2 $$
So
$$E[S_{n+1}^2|S_n] = S_n^2 + 2S_nE[A_n|S_n] + E[A_n^2|S_n] = S_n^2 + 0 +  (1/4)1_{\{S_n \notin\{0, 10\}\}}$$
where $1_{\{S_n \notin\{0, 10\}\}}$ is an indicator function that is 1 if $S_n \notin \{0,10\}$ and is 0 else. So 
$$E[S_{n+1}^2] = E[S_n^2] + (1/4)P[S_n \notin \{0,10\}]$$
Subtracting 25 from both sides gives
$$ Var(S_{n+1}) = Var(S_n) + (1/4)P[S_n \notin \{0,10\}]$$
and $Var(S_0)=0$ so 
$$ \boxed{Var(S_n) = (1/4)\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} P[S_i \notin \{0,10\}] \quad \forall n\in \{1, 2, 3, ...\} } $$
Since $P[S_i \notin \{0,10\}] = 1$ for $i \in \{0, 1, 2, 3, ..., 9\}$ we have $$\boxed{Var(S_1)=1/4, Var(S_2)=2/4, Var(S_3) = 3/4, ..., Var(S_{10})= 10/4}$$ 
On the other hand: 
$$ Var(S_{11}) = 10/4 + (1/4)\underbrace{(1-2(1/2)^{10})}_{P[S_{10}\notin\{0,10\}]}$$
In general, the variance increases as $n\rightarrow\infty$ to approach a 
limiting value of $25$.  It is possible to compute $P[S_i \notin \{0,10\}]$ for all $i$ (for example, by taking powers of a transition probability matrix), but this calculation is more involved.